# returning array without specific elements in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I looked really hard in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html but I couldn't find a quick functionality to this behaviour:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

arr.without(3,6) #=> [1,2,4,5]
```

I know I can write my own function/monkey-patch ruby/add a class method/write it in a few lines.

Is there a way to do this in a ruby way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can use subtraction :

```
arr - [3,6]
```

**EDIT**

if you really wanted you could alias this method

```
class Array
  alias except - 
end
```

then you can use:

```
arr.except [3,6]
```

Comment: I'm aware of array subtractions, is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: looks pretty clean to me !

Comment: yes, I use it a lot, if there is no other way I'll use that, thanks

Comment: Careful though, `Array#-` doesn't just subtract. It removes any instance of any item in the supplied parameter. So `[1,2,3,3,3] - [2,3] => [1]`. This may be something you don't expect.

Answer (score 16):

This got added in Rails 5 :)

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19082

```
module Enumerable
  def without(*elements)
    reject { |element| element.in?(elements) }
  end
end
```

it's just aesthetics, but it makes sense for the brain

Answer (score 3):

There is another way using `reject`. But it is not cleaner than `-`

```
arr.reject{|x| [3,6].include? x}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes across this and is looking for a way to delete elements from an array based on a conditional: you can use delete_if.

For example, I have a list of customers and want to merge any customers that have duplicate emails. After doing a query to get a list of all emails with the total count number for each email, I can then delete all of them that only appear once:

```
emails = Customer.select('count(email) as num_emails, email').group('email')
emails.delete_if { |email| email.num_emails.to_i == 1 }
```

The end result is I have a list of all customer emails that appear multiple times in the database.